# why is code not executing on return from Future in Dart program

Tags: dart

Could someone please explain to me why in the following code (using r25630 Windows), the value of iInsertTot at line 241 is null, or more to the point, why is line 234 ("return iInsertTot;") not executed and therefore at line 241, iInsertTot is null. The value of iInsertTot at lines 231/232 is an integer. While I can and probably should code this differently, I thought that I would try and see if it worked, because my understanding of Futures and Chaining was that it would work. I have used “return” in a similar way before and it worked, but I was returning null in those cases (eg. line 201 below).

```
/// The problem lines are :
233      fUpdateTotalsTable().then((_) {
234        return iInsertTot;
235      });
```

While running in the debugger, it appears that line 234 “return iInsertTot;” is never actually executed. Running from command line has the same result.

The method being called on line 233 (fUpdateTotalsTable) is something I am just in the process of adding, and it consists basically of sync code at this stage. However, the debugger appears to go through it correctly.

I have included the method “fUpdateTotalsTable()” (line 1076)  just in case that is causing a problem.

Lines 236 to 245 have just been added, however just in case that code is invalid I have commented those lines out and run with the same problem occurring.

```
218  /*
219   * Process Inserts
220   */
221    }).then((_) {
222      sCheckpoint = "fProcessMainInserts";
223      ogPrintLine.fPrintForce ("Processing database ......");
224      int iMaxInserts = int.parse(lsInput[I_MAX_INSERTS]);
225      print ("");
226      return fProcessMainInserts(iMaxInserts, oStopwatch);
227   /*
228   * Update the 'totals' table with the value of Inserts
229   */
230    }).then((int iReturnVal) {
231      int iInsertTot = iReturnVal;
232      sCheckpoint = "fUpdateTotalsTable (insert value)";
233      fUpdateTotalsTable().then((_) {
234        return iInsertTot;
235      });

236   /*
237   * Display totals for inserts
238   */
239    }).then((int iInsertTot) {
240      ogTotals.fPrintTotals(
241        "${iInsertTot} rows inserted - Inserts completed",
242        iInsertTot, oStopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds);
243
244      return null;
245  /*


192  /*
193   * Clear main table if selected
194   */
195    }).then((tReturnVal) {
196      if (tReturnVal)
197        ogPrintLine.fPrintForce("Random Keys Cleared");
198      sCheckpoint = "Clear Table ${S_TABLE_NAME}";
199      bool tClearTable = (lsInput[I_CLEAR_YN] == "y");
200      if (!tFirstInstance)
201        return null;
202      return fClearTable(tClearTable, S_TABLE_NAME);
203
204   /*
205    * Update control row to increment count of instances started
206    */
207    }).then((_) {

1073  /*
1074   * Update totals table with values from inserts and updates
1075  */
1076  async.Future<bool> fUpdateTotalsTable() {                                     
1077    async.Completer<bool> oCompleter = new async.Completer<bool>();
1078
1079    String sCcyValue = ogCcy.fCcyIntToString(ogTotals.iTotAmt);
1080 
1081    print ("\n*********  Total = ${sCcyValue}  \n");
1082  
1083    oCompleter.complete(true);
1084    return oCompleter.future;  
1085  }
```

Comment: That is much code, how about removing everything that isn't needed? Probably you can find the problem yourself this way.

Comment: There's really only three lines in question. The rest is included in case it causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function *L230-235* does not return anything and that's why your `iInsertTot` is `null` *L239*. To make it work you have to add a `return` at line *233*.

```
231      int iInsertTot = iReturnVal;
232      sCheckpoint = "fUpdateTotalsTable (insert value)";
233      return fUpdateTotalsTable().then((_) {
234        return iInsertTot;
235      });
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought I was familiar with using the return, however I didn't think it was used in that particular way in that particular instance, but it has burnt me before. Hopefully one day I'll master async. I'll try it and give your answer a tick thanks.